# C++ value_type of a template parameter

Tags: c++, value-type

First of all, here are my examples:

```
SymmetricMatrix<std::vector<int>, int> a;
SymmetrixMatrix<std::list<int>, int> b;
SymmetricMatrix<std::deque<double>, double> c;

SymmetricMatrix<std::vector<int> > d;
SymmetricMatrix<std::vector<double> > e;
```

So there are two template parameters. If I write a default parameter for the second one, I do not have to name it when I create the object. But how can I adjust it to the first parameter? For example if the first parameter is `std::vector<int>`, the second one should be `int`, if the first one is `std::vector<double>`, the second one should be `double`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<class DS, class T = typename DS::value_type>
class SymmetricMatrix
{
};

SymmetricMatrix<std::deque<double>> c;
```

Assumes that DS (data structure) contains typedef value_type, or it won't compile. You can replace value_type with whatever you want, so long as it's in DS.

Comment: Just important to note that `DS` actually has to define `value_type`, it's no compiler feature.

Comment: I think there should be a `typename` before `DS::value_type`.

Comment: @user2685486 vector<bool> is broken, you can google why. Either disable the specialisation if supported by your compiler, or use alternative data structure or vector<char>. basic_string<bool> seemed to work for me, if a little strange.

Comment: Thank you, it is working. There was a problem with `operator()`. Return type should be `typename std::vector<T>::reference` in case of bools. Or `typename std::vector<T>::const_reference`.